# Regular expression and unicode to extract a price in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, euro

I'm trying to extract some prices from the ikea website but the price format is pretty messy (whitespace, carriage return, a comma in the middle of nowhere). This is what I extracted :

```
        39,90 €
                            ,
```

I used Scrapy to do this, so far no problem, except that I would like to get rid of all of what is not the price (and the euro symbol) !

I tried to use this regex (in python 2.7) :

```
re(\S[0-9]+([ ,]?[ ])([0-9]{2}?)u"\u20AC")
```

I'm new in programming and I learned what is a regular expression this afternoon, but I tried a massive number of possibilities without getting any better results than :

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

If someone could take few minutes to look at what I did and tells me where I'm wrong, that would be great !

Cheers everyone

Comment: Show the `repr()` of the data you extracted, to more clearly see the sequence of characters in the data.

Comment: Here is the result :
    [u'\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t39, 90 \\u20ac\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t', u'\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t']

Comment: Instead of removing all the unneeded characters, why not capturing only the prices your are interested in? Are they consistent, i.e. always in the form of `12.34 €`?

Comment: Yep they are, always the same form and unit. How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of strings you are trying to match unicode or byte?

Suppose you are working with unicode strings then your match could look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

s = u"""        39,90 \u20AC
                  """
groups = re.match(ur'\D*(\d+)\D*(\d{0,2})\D*(\u20AC)', s, re.UNICODE)
print groups.groups()
```

output:

```
(u'39', u'90', u'\u20ac')
```

*u* in front of strings indicates that this is unicode string.

Regex explained:

1. \D* - anything that is non digit zero or more times
2. (\d+) - one or more digits
3. \D* - ...
4. (\d{0,2}) - zero or two digits
5. \D* - ...
6. (\u20AC) - unicode currency symbol

We use \D, \d along with [re.UNICODE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag so that everything that in unicode is interpreted as digit or non digit would be matched.

If you use byte strings. I assume that you are working with utf-8 byte strings. Then:

```
import re

s = b"""        39,90 \xE2\x82\xAC
                  """

groups = re.match(r'\D*(\d+)\D*(\d{0,2})\D*(\xE2\x82\xAC)', s)
print groups.groups()
```

output:

```
('39', '90', '\xe2\x82\xac')
```

"\xe2\x82\xac" is "e282ac" byte sequence that in utf-8 encoding means euro sign.

Good practise called "Unicode sandwich":

1. Decode bytes to unicode on input
2. Work only with unicode
3. Encode unicode to bytes on output

Comment: That's great, the Unicode version works fine, even if there is still some remaining comma, removing them will train me to deal with regex ! Thank you !